# what is the best way to iterate through columns starting at one column and jumping to another one in Pandas

Tags: pandas

If I have a dataframe such as

```
something  A_x  A_y  B_x  B_y C_x  C_y
1          3     4    2     3   4   3
2          2     1    3     5       7
```

I want to iterate through it with a for loop. So far I know that doing

```
for column in df.columns[1::2]
    print(colum)
```

will give me:

```
A_x
B_x
C_x
```

which is *very close* to what I want to achieve.

What I want is the following:

```
A_x  A_y
B_x  B_y
C_x  C_y
```

that means that even if I jump two positions, I want to get the next one as well (as a pair or as individuals it does not matter)

Take into account that later I want to use that to have the columns so that it has to give me something similar to

```
for column in df.columns[1::2]
    print(df[colum])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try `zip` it

```
for x in zip(df.columns[::2], df.columns[1::2]):
    print(x)
        
('A_x', 'A_y')
('B_x', 'B_y')
('C_x', 'C_y')
```

Comment: Judging from OP’s output, I think it should be `[1::2]` and `[2::2]`.